# Relative clause and ending the sentence with preposition

Tags: prepositions, relative-clauses

I took one problem from my book:

> A friend is going to the cinema. You want to know the name of the
> film. You say:
>
> **Key answer**: *What's the name of the film you're going to see?*

Can I say something like this:

> What's the name of the film in the cinema you're going to?

It sounds OK to me, but I want to now whether this is grammatical or not and please tell me why the reason and the alternative if it's not. Thanks!

Comment: the film **at the cinema** [i.e. movie house]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the cinema is not needed. **going to** at the end is fine.

Declarative sentence: X is the name of the movie **we are going to see**. Question sentence form: What's the name of the movie you're going to [see?].

In fact, in English, there are many, many times in speech where the verb after ***to*** is left out if it is understood.

Here are a few examples:

Q: Would they like to go out with us?
A: They'd like to [go out with us] but they can't.

Person 1: I want to **go early** so I can get a seat at the event.
Person 2: Yes, I want to, too.

Person 1: We wouldn't go to the bank if **we didn't want to** [go to the bank], would we?
Person 2: No, we wouldn't.

This can get complicated but basically the idea is that you do not need to repeat certain verbs or verb phrases, if they are already known.

Answer (score -1):

> [2] What's the name of the film in the cinema you're going to?

[2] is incomplete.

We could say

> What's the name of the film [being screened] in the cinema you're going to?

Comment: No, it is not incomplete at all. But "in the cinema" (which is "at the cinema") is not needed. It is very common in spoken English to not repeat a verb and leave the preposition to at the end of a sentence.